# Start Android Activity on its own and start another Activity from it?

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

Is there a way to launch an activity such that it displays in a similar way to "launchMode=singleInstance" but still can launch other activities using startActivityForResult?

I want to start an activity in dialog form from a widget but I don't want to bring up the main application if it's running.

Thanks!

Comment: You should still be able to use startActivityForResult, you just won't actually receive the result so it doesn't make sense as you can just use startActivity. What would be the purpose of returning a result if you want the activity dead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) flag.

Just set this flag on your intent and you should get the behavior you want.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

NOTE: It will only create a new task if the activity you're trying to start isn't already running in a task.  Otherwise it brings that task to the front.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  For reference,  I was using addFlags before which did not work.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to make it not bring the existing activities to the front?

I tried adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK, but that doesn't appear to do anything?

Comment: If you can describe the behavior you're going for and the problem you're trying to solve, I may better be able to answer that.